# What is the user of task/perform in ES6 Generator Code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

I have an Ember application and somewhere in my project, I can see the following code written in ES6.

```
expandRow: task(function* (row, data, params){
    var $this = this;
    // Some code
    // ...
    // ...
    // const response = yield this.someServerCall(url, params);
    // ...
    // ...  
});
```

The above is called somewhere using

```
this.get('expandRow').perform(row, data, params);
```

Looking at the above, while I do have an idea about the Generator syntax in ES6, I am a bit confused about the use of "task" and "perform" specifically.

I could not find that documented anywhere. Also I could not find any custom definitions for those in my code.
Where should I look to understand more about the syntax?

Comment: Those appear to be from ember-concurrency: http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/task-function-syntax/

Comment: @NicholasTower just found the same link myself. I searched for "ember expandrow task perform" and got to that documentation.

Comment: @VLAZ my search was "generator function task perform" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all documented in the task-function-syntax area on the ember docs

> http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/task-function-syntax/

Example from the docs:

```
pickRandomNumbers: task(function * () {
  let nums = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    nums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }

  this.set('status', `My favorite numbers: ${nums.join(', ')}`);
}),
```

The `perform` function is just a way to executing said task.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Just had a quick follow up question; On the homepage it says - Tasks, unlike Promises, support cancelation.

Could you please explain what that means exactly ?

Comment: Sure...Done that

Comment: Thanks. Essentially what that boils down to is that the native Promise api doesn't have any way to cancel a promise once it's initiated. However, embed has a way to cancel something after you've send it off. You can cancel it by using `task.cancel`/`task.cancelAll`. The `task` is what's returned from the the `task.perform` call. TL;DR Promises don't have a way to cancel them after you initiate them. Ember Tasks do.